# How to convert "raw regex string" to Java compatible regex string?

Tags: java, regex

There is a difference between raw regex expressions and Java regex expressions. For example, in raw expression "\(" matches "(", but in Java you need to use "\\(".

I have a text box **for user to enter standard raw regex expressions** (1. I assume they are not Java programmers, otherwise I'll just let them input Java regex String; 2. What they enter in not a string to be searched, but a regex pattern to be used to search another string). For example they would input "\$" if they want to search "$" in a string.

Once I get user-input, I want to convert the raw expressions to Java compatible regex expressions so that I can use `Pattern` to match that regex. How should I perform the conversion?

My current understanding is that I only have to replace all "\" in raw regex string with double backslash "\\". Is that really the case? What have I missed?

I think `Pattern.quote` has nothing to do with my case because it is used to treat the string as a literal, taking each character as it is, without any regex special meaning. But in contrary, I just want to perform regex searches.

For example, if I have a String "Long1". A normal regex pattern "Long.?" would match it. But if I use  `Pattern.quote("Long.?")` it would not match, because it is a normal string, not a regex pattern, and would only match "Long.?".

Comment: It’s a bit better after your edit. Now it sounds like you don’t need to do anything. You only need to escape with backslashes in Java source code. You don’t need to do that if you are taking user input.

Comment: @Sweeper What I get from users are not string literals. I actually want them to give me regex patterns, and I 'll show them the match results (using their regex to perform search on some strings in the database). I assume they are not Java developer so they would enter standard regex strings

Comment: “What I get from users are not string literals.” Exactly, so you don’t need to escape them. You only need the backslashes in a string literal. Did you actually try what I suggested (not doing anything)? What results did you get?

Comment: As stated, escaping backslashes is only needed when writing string literals in source code. It's for the _Java compiler_ at compile-time. Getting a string from the user happens at _run-time_, so the Java compiler is not involved. Just do `Pattern.compile(userInput)`.

Comment: You are confusing java String *literals* with java Strings. Strings that are java regexes are just like any other language/tool, ie `\(` will match a bracket (in fact `\\(` would match a backslash and start a group). But when you *code* the String you must escape the escape character, so to write the String `\(` into your program, you would *code* `String regex = "\\(";` which creates the String `"\("`.

Comment: I think I've got  the point: 1. So there is a difference between "string" (for example "\\("and "string internal representation/string literal". (for example "\\\(") . What `Pattern` sees is a "string",  not the internal representation.  2. When  user types "\\(" in the input text box, it is a string,but the string object I get  is "\\\(". When this object is passed to `Pattern`,  `Pattern` sees the  string "\\(", so it is identical to what the user wants.

Comment: Yes and no. A string literal only exists in the source code, before compilation. When you have `"Foo"` in the source code, Java compiles that to create a `String` with the code points `70 111 111`. But there needs to be a way to insert characters such as newlines, carriage returns, backspaces, tabs, or even double quotes. To do this, Java provides escape sequences. `"Foo\n"` will compile to a `String` with the code points `70 111 111 10` (notice it's not `70 111 111 92 110`). Yet what if you want to have a literal backslash in the string? Well, just escape it with another backslash.

Comment: However, this specific backslash escape only has meaning with string literals in the source code. When the user types `Foo\n` in a text box, the backslash is not an escape. The `String` created has the code points `70 111 111 92 110`, not `70 111 111 10`. Now, it's a little confusing, but `Pattern` **also** uses backslashes to escape special characters; this is entirely separate from the escape sequences used by string literals.

Comment: So user-input is not a string literal, and string literals only exist in code. In my specific case  user-input string can be guaranteed to be the same as what `Pattern` sees it, not because they are string literals, but because Java automatically escapes backslashes in user input . Thank @Slaw for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Correct conclusion, but slightly wrong reasoning. It's not that Java "_automatically escapes backslashes in user input_", it's that the backslash **does not denote an escape sequence** because the user input is not a string literal nor is it processed by the Java compiler. It's just a backslash same as if you were typing in a text editor. If you pass the `String` to `Pattern::compile` then **it's the `Pattern` class** that will interpret any backslash as an escape character, not the Java language/compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My current understanding is that I only have to replace all "\" in raw regex string with double backslash "\\". Is that really the case?

### NO.

Regular expressions in Java use the same characters that are used in other languages.

What you are missing is that in Java (and C and C++) **source code,** a backslash starts an [escape sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-EscapeSequence).  Although a coder must type multiple characters to complete an escape sequence, the escape sequence represents **one character.**

Here are some examples of **single chararacters** in Java code:

```
char tab = '\t';
char newline = '\n';
char singleQuote = '\'';
char backslash = '\\';
```

Here are some Strings containing those characters.  The crucial point here is that each of these Strings has a length of one.  Each contains **only a single character.**

```
String tab = "\t";
String newline = "\n";
String doubleQuote = "\"";
String backslash = "\\";
```

Now, suppose someone wants to create a regular expression, like:

```
\(S+\)
```

That is a regular expression consisting of six characters.

In Java, the regular expression would be exactly the same.  It would be a String consisting of six characters.

Recall that this is a String consisting of **one character:**

```
String s = "\\";
```

Here is a String consisting of two characters:

```
String s = "\\(";
```

And here is a String consisting of all six characters:

```
String s = "\\(S+\\)";
```

If you print that string with this code:

```
String s = "\\(S+\\)";
System.out.println(s);
```

You will see this:

```
\(S+\)
```

Because even though the **source code** uses doubled backslashes, each pair of them represents **one character.**

So, no, you must not “translate” a user-entered string.  It’s exactly right as it is.  Only in source code would you need to double the backslashes, and even then, each pair of backslashes would still represent a single character in the string.

Side note:  your application will have to handle the possibility that the user entered an invalid regular expression (such as text with unbalanced parentheses).  Typically, something like:

```
Pattern pattern;
try {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(userEnteredText);
} catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    errorMessageLabel.setText("Invalid regular expression: " + e);
    return;
}
```